# NSString from Unicode

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring

I have a bunch of unicode characters wrapped up into NSNumber like so :

```
@(0x1f4de),    // EntypoIconTypePhone
@(0x1f4f1),    // EntypoIconTypeMobile
@(0xe789),     // EntypoIconTypeMouse
@(0xe723),     // EntypoIconTypeAddress
@(0x2709),     // EntypoIconTypeMail
@(0x1f53f),    // EntypoIconTypePaperPlane
@(0x270e),     // EntypoIconTypePencil
```

These are Icons from the Entypo font (highly recommended).

This is the code I am using to create NSString from the unicode :

```
NSNumber *u = self.unicodeLookup[type];

int unicode = [u intValue];
UniChar chars[] = {unicode};

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:chars length:sizeof(chars) / sizeof(UniChar)];
```

What I am finding is that some of these icons are being created as expected but not all of them; and from what I can see it is the unicodes which have 5 digits in them that are not being created properly.

For example, these work :

```
@(0xe723),     // EntypoIconTypeAddress
@(0x2709),     // EntypoIconTypeMail
```

but these don't :

```
@(0x1f4de),    // EntypoIconTypePhone
@(0x1f4f1),    // EntypoIconTypeMobile
```

I'm pretty sure this is my conversion code. I don't really understand all this encoding malarky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store your character constants using `unichar`, rather than `NSNumber` objects, then the compiler itself will tell you the reason:

```
unichar chars[] = 
{
    0xe723,     // EntypoIconTypeAddress
    0x2709,     // EntypoIconTypeMail
    0x1f4de,    // EntypoIconTypePhone
    0x1f4f1     // EntypoIconTypeMobile
};

Implicit conversion from 'int' to 'unichar' (aka 'unsigned short') changes value from 128222 to 62686
Implicit conversion from 'int' to 'unichar' (aka 'unsigned short') changes value from 128241 to 62705
```

As iOS/OSX uses 16-bit representation of unicode characters internally, and `0x1f4de` and `0x1f4f1` are both 32-bits, you are going to need to encode those characters as surrogate pairs:

```
a = 0x1f4de - 0x10000 = 0xf4de
high = a >> 10 = 0x3d
low = a & 0x3ff = 0xde
w1 = high + 0xd800 = 0xd83d
w2 = low + 0xdc00 = 0xdcde

0x1f4de (UTF-32) = 0xd83d 0xdcde (UTF-16)
```

(See this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Example_UTF-16_encoding_procedure)).

The upshot is that you cannot use a single array of unicode characters as you are going to have to know the length of each character's encoding.

Comment: I did manage to get the characters in your example to display by using the code in my second comment. The only problem now is the Social Font characters. Thanks for your advice though, I will play around to see if I can get those to work too.

Comment: I noticed the warnings when I used unichar but it works if I just cast my array to int.

Comment: @LeeProbert `int` will always be at least 32-bits, but `unichar` is always 16-bit.  An option for you would be to store your chars as UTF-32 (in an `unsigned`, not `unichar`) and then use `[NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding:]` with an encoding of `NSUTF32StringEncoding`, however there might be endianness issues to resolve (I haven't looked into it).

Comment: Yes. Using NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding helped for those first chunk of characters. The social font is a different font but it seems that those 0xF*** characters are not in the same range.

Comment: I have created a gist for my class here : https://gist.github.com/leeprobert/5705732 - do you fancy having a quick look at it when you get some time? The fonts can be downloaded from http://www.entypo.com/

Comment: @LeeProbert OK, will have to be later this evening though; laying flooring which makes you appreciate why you make a living using a keyboard...

Comment: np, appreciate the help. I think you'll like the class if I can get it working anyway.

Comment: @LeeProbert OK, conversation moved to gist.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct because it will help anyone else doing this. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

If I use this to create my String it works for the Entypo font unicode int values :

```
int unicode = uniChars[type];

NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&unicode length:sizeof(unicode)  encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

`uniChars` is a `CArray` of `int`s instead of the `NSArray` of `NSNumber`s I had previously. No reason for this really, it should work with both.

**UPDATE :**

There's still a problem with some of the unicode numbers. The Entypo Social font characters are not displaying. The difference between these and the normal icons is that they all start with F and have 4 characters:

```
0xF300 ,         //   EntypoIconSocialTypeGithub,
0xF301 ,         //   EntypoIconSocialTypeCGithub,
0xF303 ,         //   EntypoIconSocialTypeFlickr,
0xF304 ,         //   EntypoIconSocialTypeCFlickr,
```

I suspect the encoding would be different.